# rails 3 searching and ordering by two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of questions with different positions and question group ids
how would i find all the questions with one id and pick out the one with the biggest position number.

is this close

```
<%= @question = Question.maximum('position', :conditions => {'question_group_id' => question_group_id'}) %>
```

using any of the answers i get

```
#<Question:0x3fe85c0>
```

how do i turn that into something  we can read

Comment: Accept one answer, which fits as solution for your question ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of I see an `erb` tag (`<% %>`) and the operation you perform will be better on your controller.

Now the query (in the controller) should be

```
@question = Question.where(question_group_id: question_group_id).
  order("position desc").
  limit(1). #because you only need one record!
  first
```

Comment: Just doing .first without the limit will just retrieve the first record.  You don't need the .limit(1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following query.This will defiantly work for you.

```
@question = Question.where('question_group_id = ?',question_group_id).order("position desc").first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@question = Question.where(:question_group_id => question_group_id).order("position desc").first
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would put the query on the Model as a named scope and not in the Controller.

Given that, on your Question model:

```
scope :highest_position_by_question_group_id, lambda { |question_group_id| 
  where(question_group_id: question_group_id).order('position DESC').first
}
```

And on your Controller:

```
@question = Question.highest_position_by_question_group_id(question_group_id)
```